# Add layout at bottom with edit text on it and hide it if the edit text is not focused

Tags: android, layout, android-edittext

How to add layout at bottom with edit text on it when pressed button "plus" and hide the layout if the edit text is not focused
**please look at this picture** [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRyC7.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your layout must have a `ListView`, an `EditText`, and a `FloatingActionButton`. Place all these within a `RelativeLayout`. An example of this would be

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"    
tools:context="abcd.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/fab"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Input"
        android:id="@+id/input"
        />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_above="@id/fab"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:id="@+id/list"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The back button by default does the function of closing the TextInputLayout. To close it on touching it outside, you can add the following to your activity.

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
    View v = getCurrentFocus();
    if ( v instanceof EditText) {
        Rect outRect = new Rect();
        v.getGlobalVisibleRect(outRect);
        if (!outRect.contains((int)event.getRawX(), (int)event.getRawY())) {
            v.clearFocus();
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }
}
return super.dispatchTouchEvent( event );
}
```

Comment: If this answered solved the question, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Add `OnFocusChangeListener` to the `EditText` and inside the Overrided `onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus)` method add or remove your layout based on `hasFocus` value (its true if it has focus).

Refer [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnFocusChangeListener.html) for more on `OnFocusChangeListener`